# Pass a variable on a call in Python to bisect arduino action

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy, arduino-yun

Total noob with Python writing, so pease be kind.
I have been trying for hours to solve this and so long I am not able.
The only work I have done in Python was much simpler and didn't involve libraries.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/amicojeko/TwitterBlink) Python code to implement an Arduino action on my Yún. It is based on Tweepy library.
My main goal is to insert three hashtags and do 3 different things in Arduino depending on which hashtag has been tweeted.
So, everything is working fine and my LED is blinking whenever any of the hashtag is tweeted. 
What I want to do now is bisect code to be run on Arduino.

This is part of my streaming.py code:

```
search_string = '#jekotest'

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

"""
A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
"""

def on_data(self, data):
    # I call an external script because the Arduino's Bridge library
    # confilcts with the tweepy library
    call(["/usr/bin/python", script_path + "/go.py"])
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    # TODO: Put some error handling here
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=[search_string])
```

And this is go.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/lib/python2.7/bridge/')

from bridgeclient import BridgeClient as bridgeclient

value = bridgeclient()
value.put('go','1')
```

I know that stream.body is a dict containing {'track': '#jekotest'} so:
How the heck could I do a

```
if '#jekotest' in stream.body:
value.put('go', 1)
elif: 
'#anotherhashtag' in stream.body
value.put('go', 2)
```

And so on?

Thank you so much

Comment: OK, first point achieved.
I'm passing an argument on the call. 
Now I need to know which hashtag is firing the call in order to take different paths.
Still working on it, any thought on tweepy would be appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly the solution I was looking for, but it is a solution (specially for total noobs like me): just pass an argument with the call to the go.py file:
`call(["/usr/bin/python", script_path + "/go.py, myArgument"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to put both files together and make it work like this:

```
hashtag = status.entities['hashtags']
    for value in hashtag:
        if translateHashtag1 in value['text']:
            goBridge.put('go', 1)
```